# Check if null can be assigned to an instance of given type

Tags: c#, types, null, instance

I have a Type-object, `myType`. Is there a way to check if null can be assigned to an instance of said type?

```
if (CanAssignNull(myType))
    // can assign null
else
    // cannot assign null
```

Comment: @GiladGreen - It sounds like the `myType` could be a reference-type, so it wouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: @Enigmativity If it’s a reference type, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @GiladGreen - Why delete your comment? It makes it hard to follow the comment threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity The duplicate suggestion gets removed automatically when the question is closed as a duplicate with that duplicate target.